# What is this shape, and how can I use it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes, pathfinder, anchor-point

I am working from a clipart file I did not make, in Illustrator.

I would like to "simplify" this shape - that is, remove the anchor points inside of it to only preserve the outline:

[image]

I have found that only the **Direct Selection Tool** followed by pressing the **Delete Key** can remove the middle anchor and curves associated to it (the Delete Anchor Point Tool won't do anything).

However, after removing the central anchor and getting what seems to be a clean, simple shape, it still doesn't "play nice" with other shapes: for example, it doesn't allow me to make a **Pathfinder Unite** action. I put the file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/problem-shape) and two "ears" on each side for you to try **Pathfinder Unite** if you want (if there's a better file hosting site, please let me know in comments and I will change its location).

**What is wrong with this shape and how can I make it behave normally?**

Comment: Have you tried Object > Expand?

Comment: @curious no because it's [not an option](https://imgur.com/a/Yart0s5).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>(I didn't download anything.. but it is simple identification merely looking at the posted image.)</sup>

That is a **[mesh](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html)** object. Either a gradient mesh or an envelope mesh. There's nothing "wrong" with the shape. Meshes merely aren't "simple" objects and don't behave like simple objects. "Anchors" in mesh objects not only serve as construction indicators, but also *color or transformation* indicators.

You **can't** "unmesh" a mesh object in Illustrator - seriously, it's not possible. And Pathfinder/Shape Builder are relatively useless for mesh objects. If anything, mesh objects can seem to behave closer to raster objects where these commands are concerned.

You ***can*** select the object and use **`Object > Path > Offset Path`** **set to 0**. This will create a *new* path which mimics the overall shape of the mesh. Then simply delete the mesh object. This is really the only method I'm aware of to get the overall shape, without the mesh construction - of course, anchor placement on the new path will most likely *not* mimic the anchor placements on the mesh object, even though the path will be similar.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks

Comment: "There's nothing wrong with the shape" Yay for being tolerant & inclusive towards all shapes and sizes of vectors! ;)